# Speed up reading a large Excel worksheet using Python (openpyxl)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, cython, cythonize

I am trying to read and clean data in an Excel worksheet and import the cleaned data into a MySQL database. My issue is the reading portion of the Excel worksheet is taking too long. I want to optimize this time as much as possible.

I have tried the following:

```py
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows


start_time = datetime.datetime.now()

wb = load_workbook(filename='Book1.xlsx', read_only=True, data_only=True)
ws=wb.active
column = ws.max_column
row = ws.max_row

for i in range(1, row+1):
    for j in range(1, column+1):
        cell_obj = ws.cell(row=i, column=j)
        if cell_obj.value != None:
            print(cell_obj.value)
    print('----------------This Row this execute--------------------------------')

end_time = datetime.datetime.now()
print(end_time-start_time)
```

*I highly appreciate any suggestions, such as Cython, but please do not advise using a CSV file.*

Comment: I have open issue on [git](https://github.com/dilshod/xlsx2csv/issues/201). for look for help.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly advise using Pandas as it has [read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) and [to_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) functions, which are exactly what you're trying to do. Also, Pandas is very fast.

syntax and best practices means your code will look like:

```py
df = pd.read_excel("path/to/file")
df.to_sql("a_connection_string")
```

Really, that's it!

Comment: Thanks for your response but its getting MemoryError due to read all row at a time .is there any way to read chunk-wise data because i want cleanup my excel and then import in SQL

Comment: Ultimately Pandas `read_excel` uses one of `openpyxl` or `xlrd`, so it's unlikely to be that much faster

Comment: @DavidW i am totally agree with you. i can read this excel by unzip excel into xml and try to read this xml sheet this more fast. **ThankyouGuysForyourSupports**